# H1 disappears on mobile devices. Can I force it to always appear?

Tags: html, css

I got the slider in a page in it there are couple of `<a>` and 1 `<h1>`  and  images as background but when I got to smaller resolution the text go away.  I was using bootstrap but I don't see any of the properties that might apply that. More so the other headers on the page that are not in the slider keeps getting shown. So my question is can what is the best way to force element always on top. I am posting the properties that h1 from debug while it disappear since the css and html are quite lage.

```
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position-x: 0%;
background-position-y: 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 30px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 5px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Here is the HTML

```
<section class="slider">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item"> <img data-src="images/slider/slider2.jpg" alt="First slide" src="images/slider/slider2.jpg">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="" data-tag="text5">Text5 text5 text5 text5</h1>
            <p data-tag="text6">Text6 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5 text5</p>
            <p><a data-tag="text6001" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button" >get started</a><a data-tag="text6002" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item active"> <img data-src="images/slider/slider.jpg" alt="Second slide" src="images/slider/slider.jpg">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="" data-tag="text1">Text1 text1 text1 text1 text1text1text1 text1text1 .</h1>
            <p data-tag="text2">text2 text2text2 text2text2text2 text2text2text2text2 text2text2</p>
            <p><a data-tag="text2001" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">get started</a><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button" data-tag="text2002">read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item"> <img data-src="images/slider/slider1.jpg" alt="Third slide" src="images/slider/slider1.jpg">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="" data-tag="text3" >Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3</h1>
            <p data-tag="text4">Text4 text4 text4text4text4text4text4text4 text4text4  text4</p>
            <p><a data-tag="text4001" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">get started</a><a data-tag="text4002" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#" role="button">read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon carousel-control-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon carousel-control-right"></span></a> </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please point me to my error snice I have read that one before. I know my question isn't the best one but I didn't have an idea how to make it better. Since the issue is quite stupid itself :)

Comment: We're looking for a verifiable example, something we can test. There's no way to reproduce the issue with only the included `CSS`. Please include the needed `HTML` to reproduce the issue fully.

Comment: it's  a bit and I am getting trouble formatting it as code  and let me try again

Comment: There's a "tidy" button in the code editor screen which should help you with the formatting

Comment: I am using it for quite a while more often I use ctr + k just the first time for some reason didn't format the code :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209238/discussion-between-andy-hoffman-and-hristo-alexsiev).